# Parsing HTML page using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I started working on beautifulsoup for parsing HTML.
for eg for site "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLCB1"

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

import urllib2, sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

site= "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLCB1"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

table = soup.find('table', {'class':'infobox'})
#print table
rows = table.findAll("th")
for x in rows:
    print "x - ", x.string
```

I am getting output as None in some cases of th where there is url. why it is so?

output :

```
x -  Phospholipase C, beta 1 (phosphoinositide-specific)
x -  Identifiers
x -  None
x -  External IDs
x -  None
x -  None
x -  Molecular function
x -  Cellular component
x -  Biological process
x -  RNA expression pattern
x -  Orthologs
x -  Species
x -  None
x -  None
x -  None
x -  RefSeq (mRNA)
x -  RefSeq (protein)
x -  Location (UCSC)
x -  None
```

for example, after Location, there is one more th which contains "pubmed search" but appearing as None. I want to know why its happening.

and
second : is there way to get th and respective td in dictionary so that it becomes easy to parse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Element.string`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) only contains a value if there is text *directly in the element*. Nested elements are not included.

If you are using BeautifulSoup 4, use [`Element.stripped_strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) instead:

```
print ''.join(x.stripped_strings)
```

For BeautifulSoup 3, you'll need to search for all text elements:

```
print ''.join([unicode(t).strip() for t in x.findAll(text=True)])
```

If you want to combine `<th>` and `<td>` elements into a dictionary, you'd have loop over all `<th>` elements, then use `.findNextSibling()` to locate the corresponding `<td>` element, and combine that with the above `.findAll(text=True)` trick to build yourself a dictionary:

```
info = {}
rows = table.findAll("th")
for headercell in rows:
    valuecell = headercell.findNextSibling('td')
    if valuecell is None:
        continue
    header = ''.join([unicode(t).strip() for t in headercell.findAll(text=True)])
    value = ''.join([unicode(t).strip() for t in valuecell.findAll(text=True)])
    info[header] = value
```

Comment: This only works with bs4. @sam may be using the earlier version of BeautifulSoup instead. (Not my -1 btw)

Comment: @unutbu: bugger.. Updated to include a BS3 option

Comment: ur updated answer helps thanks alott.. can u tell me answer of my second question too ?

Comment: @sam: Added a info-table-to-dict snippet there for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters :  u r a very good coder and thanks alot for help. i learn lot from u too. God Bless u !!!

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the html,

```
<th colspan="4" style="text-align:center; background-color: #ddd">Identifiers</th>
</tr>
<tr class="">
<th style="background-color: #c3fdb8"><a href="/wiki/Human_Genome_Organisation" title="Human Genome Organisation">Symbols</a></th>
<td colspan="3" class="" style="background-color: #eee"><span class="plainlinks"><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.genenames.org/data/hgnc_data.php?hgnc_id=15917">PLCB1</a>; EIEE12; PI-PLC; PLC-154; PLC-I; PLC154; PLCB1A; PLCB1B</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="">
<th style="background-color: #c3fdb8">External IDs</th>
```

You'll see in between the `Identifiers` and `External IDs` there is a `<th>` tag with no text, only an `<a>` tag:

```
<th style="background-color: #c3fdb8"><a href="/wiki/Human_Genome_Organisation" title="Human Genome Organisation">Symbols</a></th>
```

This `<th>` has no text. So `x.string` is `None`.

Comment: Sure `x.string` is None, but how do you work around that problem? :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I was getting to that, but you answer too quickly :)

Comment: what about last case where there is <th> as well as <a> tag

Comment: @sam: The middle `<th>` has an `<a>` tag, but no text. This is the tag, `x` whose `x.string` is `None`. Use `x.findAll(text=True)` (as in MartijnPieters' answer) to grab text inside the `<a>` tag as well.